# How can I assign values to a variable structure in VB 2019?

Tags: vb.net, function, structure

I have a 2 structures or more:

```
Private Structure structure_one
    Public id As String
    Public name As String
End Structure

Private Structure structure_two
    Public counter As integer
    Public code_value As String
    Public foo as string
End Structure
```

I want to call a subfunction that can take that structure by reference and assign values to the variables inside of the structure. Note that the structures name variables and total variables are not the same.

Pseudocode:

Sub my_subfunction(ByRef struc As structure)

struc.variable(0)="the id"

struc.variable(1)="the name"

end sub

calling the sub would be something like:

call my_subfunction(structure_one)

The subfunction has to be able to detect the number of elements the structure has, so it can pass all new values to the structure... The rub is that its not always the same structure, sometimes it might pass structure_one, and sometimes structure_two, or another structure... any ideas?

The porpouse of this is for cleaner code, it will save a lot of coding in larger projects

Thanks for the help

Comment: There's no such thing as a "subfunction". The general term is "method". In VB.NET, a method that does not return anything is denoted by the keyword `Sub`, short for "subroutine", and is often referred to as a "procedure", while a method that does return something is denoted by the keyword `Function`.

Comment: You are preparing for a future that should never come. Using mutable structures with public fields is just bad. Classes with public properties is what you should be using.

Answer (score 0):

You totally can "detect" which structure your method just received. Here's some skeleton code for you:

```
Private Sub AssignValuesToMyStructures(struct As Object)
    Select Case True
        Case TypeOf struct Is Structure_one
            'do stuff
        Case TypeOf struct Is Structure_two
            'do other stuff
    End Select
End Sub
```

Have fun!

Comment: That sure can help, but, its a general purpouse use sub function, wouldnt be practical to have a case for each structure it receives, but still its a good solution to some projects

Comment: As you cannot use inheritance with structures, you have to deal with every type in it's own way without hope for a cast or a common root. Using class instead would help you way more than a method which can recognize structures, but I worked on the assumption that it was out of the question (if the projects already exist it would mean a lot of refactoring).

Comment: Im creating routines for future projects that dont really exist right now, so when the time comes, ill be ready, but in order for that to work, the routines have to be as general as posible... Im not really sure how can i acomplish this with a class (never created one before), thanks for the help..!